# Error en sentencia SQL, en Workbench MySql

Tags: mysql

Estoy haciendo dos ejercicios desde **Workbench**. El ejercicio pide crear una *tabla* llamada **CLIENTES** con los siguientes campos:

**cod**: entero de tamaño 5 con rellenado de ceros, no acepta nulos.

**nombre**: texto variable de 30, no acepta nulos.

**apellidos:** texto variable de 50, no acepta nulos.

**saldo**: numero con 2 decimales y una resolución de 6 dígitos. No aceptará números negativos. Valor por defecto 1000.

Este es el query:

```
CREATE TABLE CLIENTES

cod(5) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY

nombre (30) NULL

apellidos (50) NULL

saldo (2,6) NOT NULL default 1000
```

y muestra un error de: **error code 1046, no database selected**

[image: error sql]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Por lo general cuando inicias Workbench no tienes seleccionada ninguna base de datos y es eso lo que te arroja

`error code 1046, no database selected`

En español sería

`error código 1046, no se ha seleccionado base de datos`

selecciona primero la base de datos a la que quieres agregarle la tabla con el comando

```
USE myDataBase;
```

Donde myDatabase es el nombre de tu base de datos y después ejecutas la sentencia que ya tienes

Comment: Muchas gracias, nunca había trabajado con SQL y nos mandaron a hacer esas consultas directamente en Workbench. Y pensaba que poniendo el SQL ya lo creaba directamente. Muchas gracias :)

Answer (score 2):

El error es bastante claro, `No database selected`, debes seleccionar una base de datos antes de proceder a crear una tabla o ejecutar tus `querys` debes seleccionar la base de datos mediante el siguiente *"comando/query"*:

```
USE nombre_base_de_datos;
```

O bien, dando *doble click* sobre la base de datos que deseas usar en la parte izquierda del cliente (como puedes ver, al dar *doble click* se pone en negrita el nombre de la base de datos que estamos usando en el momento):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Esa sintaxis es incorrecta. Desde Workbench puedes crear una tabla de dos formas:

Opción 1: Con sintaxis SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `INSETA_EL_NOMBRE_DE_TU_BASE_DE_DATOS`.`clientes` (
  `cod` int(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `apellidos` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `saldo` decimal(6, 2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cod`)
);
```

Opción 2: Rellenando un formulario desde la interfaz gráfica de Workbench. Es un formulario simple que rellenas indicando el tipo de datos de los campos, el nombre... y te genera el la consulta SQL correspondiente y la ejecuta. Mira este [enlace](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-create-new-table.html)